# How can you specify additional ActiveModel Serializer attributes at runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

There are a lot of SO posts that talk about removing attributes or making attributes optional at runtime.

How do you configure and call an ActiveModel::Serializer so there is a default set of attributes and then at runtime, client code can specify a set of additional attributes to include?

Here is an example:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, email

  def roles
    @object.roles.map(&:name)
  end
end

us = UserSerializer.new(User.first, also: [:first_name, :roles])
us.as_json
# Expected:
# {:id => 1, :email => "user@example.com", :first_name => "Bob", :roles => [:admin, :employee]}
```

Obviously the `:also` keyword is not supported, is there another way?

Comment: Are you planning on getting the client-specified attributes via a controller? If so, you could use [strong parameters](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) and whitelist the allowed attributes. Example: `UserSerializer.new(User.first).as_json(allowed_attributes)`

Comment: That is a good point but in order to get this to work, the serializer would need to specify the entire world of attributes and then the controller specifies a subset. I'm trying to do the opposite - start with a default subset that is restrictive and allow controllers to specify a bigger set based on certain permissions.

Comment: You could use [`merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) for that. You could make a method called `default_attributes` and merge that with your `allowed_attributes` or set the default attributes in the serializer and pass your client-specified parameters to your serializer (e.g. `respond_with UserSerializer.new(User.first), client_attrs: allowed_attributes`). Then within your UserSerializer, you have access to `@options[:client_attrs]`

Comment: I am surprised that there isn't a native way to do this